# Simulating a dataset in R

Tags: r, dataset, simulate

I'm still fairly new to R and get stuck a bit. I am trying to simulate a dataset in R with certain parameters. For example, if I want my number of observations to be 100, and have x be a random normal variable where the mean is 0 and the standard deviation is 1, fulfilling the following equation y=0.7+3*x+\mu. Further, \mu is a random normal error with mean 1 and sd of 2.

Now, I have the basics of the code for the initial values, but don't know how to add in the equation or the 100 individual random normal errors.

```
 set.seed(1)
 x <- rnorm(n=100, mean=0, sd=1)
```

Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: ``set.seed(1000); n <- 100; x <- rnorm(n, 0, 1); mu <- rnorm(n, 1, 2); y <- 0.7 + 3*x + mu``

Comment: @nathanesau Thank you for your help! Do you want to make that an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typically in `R`, code in `vectorized`. For instance,

```
x <- c(1,2,3)
y <- 1 + x # 2 3 4
```

Distributions in `R` have a functions for the pdf, cdf, inverse cdf and generating random numbers. For instance,

```
pnorm() # p: probability (pdf)
dnorm() # d: distribution function (cdf)
qnorm() # q: quantile (inverse cdf)
rnorm() # r: random normal (generating random numbers)
```

Setting a seed is important in simulation so results can be reproduced. In `R` use `set.seed()`

So to answer your question:

```
set.seed(1000) 
n <- 100
x <- rnorm(n, 0, 1) # n: number observations, 0: mean, 1: sd
mu <- rnorm(n, 1, 2)
y <- 0.7 + 3*x + mu # we can do this R allows code to be vectorized
```